# Как работает OAuth2?

Tags: oauth2

Как я понимаю механиз работы OAuth2:

Есть:

а) браузер клиента

б) Сервер ресурсов

в) Авторизационный сервер (например facebook)

---

1.1 Браузер обращается на resource-server, тот отдаёт ответ 401.

2.1 Пользователь руками вводит логин/пароль от auth-сервера, браузер идет на auth-server, отправляя ему post-ом введённые логин/пароль. 

2.2 Auth-server отдаёт браузеру некий token, который будет подтверждением что браузер залогинился на auth-сервере.

3.1 Браузер идет на auth-server, отправляя ему полученный ранее token, а так же cliend_id - id приложения-сервера-ресурсов, к которому хочет получить доступ.

3.2 Auth-сервер отдаёт браузеру code.

4.1 Браузер идет на resource-server, передавая ему code.

4.2 Resource-server получает code и идет с ним на auth-server, тот генерирует access_token и refresh_token, отдаёт их resource-серверу.

4.3 Resource-server передаёт полученные access_token и refresh_token браузеру.

5.1 Браузер идет на resource-server, передавая ему access_token,

5.2 Resource-server удостоверяется в валидности access-токена, отправляя его на auth-server

5.3 Получив ответ от auth-сервера о том что access_token валидный, отдаёт в браузер запрашиваемый ресурс.

Получается, access_token браузер получает не от auth-сервера, а от resource-сервера

1. Правильно ли я понимаю схему взаимодействия между клиентом-браузером, сервером ресурсов и auth-сервером?

---

В таком случае, если имеется еще один resource-сервер, который авторизуется через тот же самый auth-server, то браузер клиента обращаясь на него без auth-токена, получит ответ 401. Потом браузер предложит пользователю ввести логин/пароль от auth-сервера, и далее те же самые действия.

2. Если это так, то данная схема не избавляет пользователя от повторного ввода логина/пароля для каждого нового приложения, несмотря на то что все они используют один и тот же auth-сервер?

---

3. Каким образом проверяется не просто аутентификация, но и авторизация пользователя? Т.е. где мы проверяем роли пользователя?